# Visualising correct maths with MathJax and mac in R markdown

Tags: macos, google-chrome, r-markdown, mathjax

I am trying to write an R Markdown presentation but I am struggling with MathJax. If I run this code:

```
---
title: My First R Markdown Presentation
output: ioslides_presentation
widgets: [mathjax]
---

$$ x = \dfrac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a} $$
```

I see the following

[image]

On the other hand, if I add the following line found on mathjax website, I obtain the right thing

```
--- 
title: My First R Markdown Presentation 
output: ioslides_presentation widgets: [mathjax]
---

<script type="text/javascript" async  
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.7/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
</script>
 
## Maths
 
$$ x = \dfrac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a} $$
```

Result:

[image]

It there a way to teach R Markdown (or the browser, Google Chrome) to recognise MathJax without having every time to add the line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.7/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
</script>
```

Thank you for any help you may give me.

Comment: I'm confused -- that doesn't look like a normal R Markdown document to me.  Why do you have `widgets: [mathjax]`?  If I leave out that line, everything is fine.  I don't need the script inclusion.

Comment: Hi, thank you for asking. If you see the first picture, the maths doesn't look right. In the second instead it does. The `widgets: [mathjax]` does not change the outcome, I put it in my code because I was taught to put it there.

Comment: When I run a document without the widgets line or the script inclusion (but with a slide marker added) I don't see a display like your first one, only like the second one.